# PHP - Array unique only using specific values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I have a PHP array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [value] => 111
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [value] => 222
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [value] => 333
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [value] => 111
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [value] => 111
        [date] => 'today'
    )
```

)

If I use array_unique like this...

```
print_r(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR));
```

It removes the duplicate [3] which is correct, but I am looking for a way to ignore [id] and only match by [date] and [value] so that my output looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [value] => 111
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [value] => 222
        [date] => 'today'
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [value] => 333
        [date] => 'today'
    )
```

)

Comment: Iterate over array and store found pairs `date-value`. If pair exists - skip array item.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302

Answer (score 4):

**`array_reduce`** + **`array_values()`** solution:

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 111, 'date'=> 'today'],
    ['id' => 2, 'value' => 222, 'date'=> 'today'],
    ['id' => 3, 'value' => 333, 'date'=> 'today'],
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 111, 'date'=> 'today'],
    ['id' => 5, 'value' => 111, 'date'=> 'today']
    ];

$result = array_values(
    array_reduce($arr, function($r, $a){
        if (!isset($r[$a['value'] . $a['date']])) $r[$a['value'] . $a['date']] = $a;
        return $r;
    }, [])
);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [value] => 111
            [date] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [value] => 222
            [date] => today
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [value] => 333
            [date] => today
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over your array and get a key as concatenation of `'date'` and `'value'` fields. If this key has already been found - skip array value:

```
$pairs = [];
$new_values = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $key = $item['date'] . $item['value'];

    if (empty($pairs[$key])) {
        $pairs[$key] = 1;
        $new_values[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your solution differ in speed or resources from RomanPerekhrests version?

Comment: You can compare this yourself. But I don't think you will find significant difference. And unless your array has millions of records you won't even feel the difference.